Has there been research on the laws of logic that hold for definite descriptions?
I have realized that not all laws of classical logic hold for definite descriptions. For example, while it is a law of logic that $(\forall x)x=x$, it is not the case that the round square is equal to the round square. Also, while in classical logic, $P \vee \neg P$ is always true, it is not the case that the round square is either round or not round. However, some laws of logic still hold for definite descriptions. For example, the law of non-contradiction, $\neg (P \land \neg P)$ holds, as does the law of symmetry of equality and the law of transitivity of equality. So, then, my question is, has there been any research at all on the subset of laws of logic that hold for definite descriptions? I would be very interested to read such a text.

what is a round square?

"it is not the case that the round square is equal to the round square" "it is not the case that the round square is either round or not round" " the law of non-contradiction, $\neg(P\vee\neg P)$ holds, as does the law of symmetry of equality and the law of transitivity of equality" Citations needed. I don't share these intuitions in general; for example, I would argue that if I'm going to treat "round square" meaningfully then I'm going to drop the law of non-contradiction for it (it's both round and not round). What background assmptions are you making here?

@NoahSchweber I am actually referring to Bertrand Russell's theory of definite descriptions. Also, in the negation of a definite description statement, I am giving the negation a narrow scope, not the wide scope. With the wide scope, yes, the law of excluded middle still holds, but with the narrow scope, it doesn't.
